# Application re-launch, elevated "runas", does not capture TaskbarButtonCreated Msg before ITaskbarList use?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder, c++builder-2010

Using Borland C++ Builder.

Before I use **ITaskbarList3**, I do as Windows requires:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391692.aspx

> Your application should call RegisterWindowMessage(L"TaskbarButtonCreated") and handle that message in its wndproc. That message must be received by your application before it calls any ITaskbarList3 method.

However this doesn't seem to work always for me, the message I'm waiting for never comes, even though RegisterWindowMessage() was successful.

After some digging I found that the problem is related to when my application relaunches itself with "runas", immediately after starting, when based on user settings, the application needs to run elevated.

The second (now elevated) run, the message I'm waiting for never comes.

I **assume** this is because Windows has sent this message already and it is not doing it again, even though a new instance is created ??

How safe is it to **assume** the message must have been sent already on a second (elevated) run, and proceed with using ITaskbarList3 anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

Your application code must call [`ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function after creating the top window and registering "TaskbarButtonCreated" message. This will allow for the second (elevated) instance to receive "TaskbarButtonCreated" message.

```
UINT nTaskbarButtonCreatedMessage = RegisterWindowMessage(TEXT("TaskbarButtonCreated"));
HWND hWnd = {create the top main window and get handle to it}.
ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx(hWnd, nTaskbarButtonCreated, MSGFLT_ALLOW, nullptr);
```

*(this is a code for VC++ but I believe it will work for Borland C++ Builder too)*

Comment: Thanks @Ruslan.  I'm getting an undefined function error even when I include windows.h .  I'm also worried it will create an error on XP as the docs state it's Windows 7 and up.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there situations where the taskbar icon is never created ?  If not, and as fallback scenario, I could assume the icon has been created when the main form is showing and the first OnIdle event is triggered.

Comment: `ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx()` is defined in `winuser.h`, which is included by `windows.h`. Make sure the `WINVER` define is `>= 0x0601` to use it. In any case, you will have to use `ChangeWindowMessageFilter()` on XP and Vista, so use `GetProcAddress()` to load `ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx()` at runtime and fallback if it is not available.

Comment: As for the `TaskbarButtonCreated` message, it is delivered when the window's Taskbar button is created (hence its name), and that does not happen until the window is shown. As long as you register the message filter after creating the window and before showing the window, you should be OK. A good place to do that is in your Form's `CreateWnd()` method (which will also allow you to re-register the message filter if the Form's `HWND` is ever recreated).

Comment: Or, you could just use `ChangeWindowMessageFilter()` at program startup before creating any windows. The ID for `TaskbarButtonCreated` will not change during the app's lifetime, so you could just register the message filter once for the entire process instead of trying to register it for individual windows.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `ChangeWindowMessageFilter` **may** become deprecated ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Comment: @RuslanGaripov: I'm aware of that, but it hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @Remy, I register the message in the forms constructor.  The form is only created once, so when re-started elevated, the form is not created in the first instance, but in the second (elevated) instance.  The second (elevated) instance however never receives the message, even though registering worked.

Comment: PS. as dirty work-around, after I posed the question, I tried checking in OnIdle if the form is showing, and if it does, I allow the use of ITaskbarList from that point onward, as if the message was received.  I do however `try{} catch(...){}` any ITaskbarList actions to make sure.  Tested and working.

Comment: @Peter: The constructor is too late. The `HWND` has already been created and the Form's DFM has already been streamed in. If this is your main form, it is displayed automatically by default, so its Taskbar button has likely already been created as well. As I said earlier, you should override the Form's virtual `CreateWnd()` method and do the filter registration from there instead. That way you can register the filter immediately after the `HWND` is created before it is manipulated too much. Of course, this assumes that `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar` is true (which it is by default)